# Exception or notification when using an undeclared taglib

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

While it's easy to trigger errors when hacking around JSP files, I frequently miss when I forget to declare a taglib used in that JSP, because there's no signal telling me. If I use an undeclared taglib, the respective code using it just ends up in HTML unparsed. For example when the taglib for `bean`...

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="bean" %>
```

is missing, usages of `<bean:message>` end up in the HTML like this:

```
...
<div id="footer">
  <bean:message key="app.title" />&nsbp;<bean:message key="app.version" />
</div>
...
```

I'd very much like to get an exception thrown in this case, or be otherwise notified. Is there a way?

Comment: Depends... do you want to hack around with the jsp compiler yourself?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I thought maybe there's some option I don't know about, which would enable some sort of notification...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Depending on how invasive patching the compiler would be, I'd be interested in using that, too, if you'd like to elaborate :)

Comment: [Jasper](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jasper-howto.html) is the tomcat jsp compiler. Since it is open source, you can modify it to behave however you like.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch So do I get it right that this is intended behaviour and by no other means overridable, than patching the compiler?

Comment: As far as I know. Note your `prefix` can be **anything**. `<%@ taglib uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" prefix="b" %>` is perfectly legal.